# Инициализация обычная и через :v_(v)

Tags: c++

Недавно возникла проблема, что программа не работала при инициализации через :v_(v), а при обычном сработало, но разобраться, в чем проблема, я, к сожалению, так и не смог.
Так что хочу спросить здесь, чем отличается такая инициализация переменных в конструкторе

```
    template<typename Iterator>
class Paginator {
public:
Paginator(Iterator begin, Iterator end, size_t page_size) : begin_(begin), end_(end), page(page_size) {    
    }
private:
    Iterator begin_, end_;
    size_t page;
};
```

От такой:

```
template<typename Iterator>
class Paginator {
public:
    Paginator(Iterator begin, Iterator end, size_t page_size){
    begin_ = begin;
    end_ = end;
    page = page_size;
    }
private:
    Iterator begin_, end_;
    size_t page;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При входе в тело конструктора все члены-данные класса должны быть инициализированы.

Когда вы пишите:

```
template <typename T>
class widget
{
public:
    widget(const T& value)
    {
        value_ = value;
    }
private:
    T value_;
};
```

`value_ = value;` - это не иницализация, а присваивание. Сначала будет вызван конструктор по умолчанию без параметров (если таковой имеется), затем будет вызвана операция копирующего присваивания (если таковая имеется).

```
widget(const T& value) :
    value_(value)
{
}
```

В таком варианте, будет вызван конструктор копирования. Используется именно такой вариант, т.к. фактически он выполнится быстрее из-за меньших затрат.
Существуют случаи когда списковая инициализация членов класса *необходима*: например инициализация константного нестатического члена (присваивание в этом случае не подойтет).

Больше [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: *"При входе в тело конструктора все члены-данные класса должны быть инициализированы"* Скорее не "инициализированы" а "созданы", или что-то в этом роде. Потому что при `T = int`, время жизни `value_` началось бы при входе в конструктор `widget`, но он не был бы инициализирован.